# How apple watch glances will appear

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

After reading documentation about glances i can't define how they will appear on the glances screen. Will it be automatically after installation or user must manually add glance to the screen (like today widget)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glances will not be added automatically.  There will be an AppleWatch companion app on the phone where you can opt in to add your Glance to the watch - much like Today Widgets

Comment: Interesting. Can you provide a link to documentation or confirmation on this?

Comment: I don't have any documentation to say so, but it makes total sense.  There's no way Apple will have glances added automatically.  That would be like Today Widgets being added for every app you install on your device. For HealthKit, there's a companion app called Fitness.  For the watch, there will be some sort of analogous thing.  It doesn't make much sense to have to configure the watch on the watch, when you have a connected iPhone right there.

Comment: Interesting thoughts. Has prompted my thinking further, which I've now turned into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have any formal guidance from Apple about how this will be managed at this point.

However, it seems highly unlikely that they will be automatically added to the Watch, without at the very least a prompt to the user asking them if they want to install them. It is less clear whether Watch glances and apps would be like third party keyboards, that sit silently in their companion app unless you visit settings to install them, or whether the installation might be a more prompted experience, such as when an app asks for permission to enable location services.

I think the most likely scenario is that configuration will be primarily (or almost entirely/entirely) on the phone, as per Joseph DeCarlo's response. However, this could also be handled akin to location services (prompt in-app on the phone to approve install, modify in Settings) as described above, or like third party keyboards solely via the (increasingly broad, and a bit confusing) Settings app. I hope that's not the case and we get a dedicated app for managing the watch, but at this point we do not have information to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine it is automatic after installation. But only shows if the user has your app open on the watch.

I am basing this on the scenario's shown in the documentation. E.g.

> while the glance for an airline app might display gate information for an upcoming flight

and how I use my Pebble, in that the application I have open is one that is meaningful to me at that time. E.g. The music controls when I am playing music on my phone. Or the Misfit App when I am walking to see how I am doing.

Until we can get our hands, or wrists, on an Apple Watch, we can't know for certain.